# NuGet update step is failing as private NuGet feed url is inaccessible from docker

Tags: docker, nuget

We are trying to create a custom image as part of containerizing our Sitecore solution. But it is failing at NuGet restore step. We are using a private NuGet feed which can be accessed only with our corporate network or via the Big IP F5 client. It looks like this NuGet repo was inaccessible from docker. (Confirmed it with the ping command). I tried passing the proxy URL via build args but still got the same error.

```
docker build --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY={username:password@proxyUrl:port} --build-arg HTTP_PROXY={username:password@proxyUrl:port} .
```

[image: private nuget feed inaccessible from docker]

Comment: Is there a VPN or MITM traffic inspection (e.g. zscaler) setup on the host machine ?

Comment: @VincentLui yes, host machine is having zscalar installed and we have no way to disable it as per our company policy. but the NuGet feed is accessible from host machine. only issue is it is not working from docker. to confirm thew connectivity I have used the ping, all the public URLs are accessible from docker only our private NuGet feed is inaccessible.

Comment: Short answer here. Look to the ZScalar section. https://vincent-lui.medium.com/running-sitecore-in-docker-containers-an-enterprise-environment-b4c1d469b423    @VincentLui you really should summarise this post here, so people actually find it ;-)

Comment: @VincentLui Also I have tried with the host which is in our corporate network and also there is no VPN or MITM installed. But still the nuget url is inaccessible from docker

Comment: @PremKumar_2530 have you setup your Docker DNS properly if there is no VPN or MITM (ZScaler) installed ?

Comment: @VincentLui Yes, we are using google DNS, "dns": [ "8.8.8.8"],

Comment: Another question, are you testing this when you are in the office or at home ? I'm having a lot of issues at the office but managed to resolve the issue at home. You can try tethering internet off your mobile if you are on the office just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @VincentLui, its more of an infra limitation to restrict the requests which are not from our company network. So, finally we decided to move the NuGet restore and build steps outside of the dockerfile (NuGet restore, and build will happen in build servers) and create an image from the build artifacts. This sitecore documentation link helped: [https://doc.sitecore.com](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/building-custom-sitecore-images.html#adjustments-for-a-traditional-build_body)